# My .htaccess file wont remove .php URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about my `.htaccess` file, it won't show the file, when typing domain.com/about, instead of domain.com/about.php

Here is my `.htaccess` code (it works on localhost), i am using ubuntu and apache2 webserver

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: needed to use this `sudo a2enmod rewrite` command on my ubuntu server to get it to work, on ubuntu 14.04 Thanks!